# Livewire no funciona en chrome, edge y todos los webkit

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, livewire, laravel-9

Estoy trabajando con Laravel y LiveWire sin embargo en todos los navegadores webkit no funciona como espero.

El mensaje que aparece en herramientas de desarrollador es el siguiente:

> Audit usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and
> navigator.platform A page or script is accessing at least one of
> navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform.

> Starting in Chrome 101, the amount of information available in the
> User Agent string will be reduced.

> To fix this issue, replace the
> usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and
> navigator.platform with feature detection, progressive enhancement, or
> migrate to navigator.userAgentData.
> Note that for performance reasons,
> only the first access to one of the properties is shown. 1 fuente
> livewire.js:1

Conozco muy poco de livewire y javascript y no sé como, ni donde (en que archivos) solucionar este error ya que tengo algunos elementos dinamicos que deben refrescarse con acciones livewire y en chrome (Webkit en general) no funcionan.

gracias

Comment: Algo de lo que estás usando intenta modificar `navigator.userAgent`, puede ser tu mismo código o alguna librería `JavaScript` que estés importando. Revisa `livewire.js` que es donde te indica el problema.

Comment: Gracias @HeytalePazguato. Revisaré lo que me comentas pues es la unica pagina que da el problema y no usa nada distinto que las demás.

Comment: Si es la única página que da problemas revisa si los componentes `livewire` están contenidos en un `div` si hay más de un componente al nivel principal del `body` entonces tiene problemas.

Comment: Gracias @HeytalePazguato he hecho esto ultimo y he modificado una de las llamadas a este y he solucionado el problema.

Comment: Perfecto, he votado para cerrar la pregunta porque al parecer era un error tipográfico y se solucionó en los comentarios. Saludos!